# notifications from a dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to get a notification when a users pushes a button to dismiss a dialog.  I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<div id="TestDialog"/>

$("#TestDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    position: ['middle', 'middle'],
    savePushed: function() {
        alert('save pushed');
    },
    closePushed: function() {
        alert('save pushed');
    },

    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            // alert('save');
            savePushed();

            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Close: function() {
            //alert('close');
            closePushed();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly define the `savePushed()` and `closePushed()` functions. Since they are not a part of [Jquery-UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), you can't set it as an option of it.

See this [working Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/BQ24J/)

**Rewrite your code to this:**

```
$("#TestDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    position: ['middle', 'middle'],
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            alert('Save button was pressed!');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Close": function() {
            alert('Close button was pressed!');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

---

## If you need

to call the function `savePushed()` or `closePushed()`, when the user presses the button, you can rewrite your code as this:

```
function savePushed() {
    alert('Save button was pressed!');
}

function closePushed() {
    alert('Save button was pressed!');
}

$("#TestDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    position: ['middle', 'middle'],
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            savePushed();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Close": function() {
            closePushed();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

See this [working Fiddle example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/BQ24J/6/)